# Why are Twilio Flex Worker attributes changing automatically? Specifically, the Roles property

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I notice that for some reason when I open up my Worker here
TaskRouter / Flex Task Assignment / Workers /
that my attributes have changed. Specifically, the Roles collection is changed as shown below (red being values BEFORE system changes them, Green being values AFTER system changes them)

What logically could be changing these values?
Its really bad because I have configured TaskRouter tasks based on this value. And when the values are changed, the tasks no longer get routed at all!

Is there anything that automatically updates these values? Spefically the Roles property? 
I cant imagine why the system would feel its ok to do this since task routing may depend on this specific property.

[image]

Comment: Hey, I see you've been asking a few questions about Flex. We have a private beta of a forum for Flex questions. Would you be interested in joining? If so, drop me an email at philnash@twilio.com and I'll get you set up.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The roles property is a special property within Flex that is set by your identity provider. It is required for permissions around Flex (agent, supervisor, admin are 3 roles I know of in particular). You can read up about [properties on your workers and how attributes map to them from the identity provider here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/configuring-single-sign-and-identity-provider-integration#identity-attributes-and-flex-roles).

For custom properties like this, I would recommend you prefix your attributes with a common namespace so that Flex/your identity provider won't clash with them.

Let me know if that helps at all.